# How to make subtableview call cellForRowAtIndexPath function

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I add a sub tableView in main view and the subView reflash its data every 2 seconds, but the cellForRowAtIndexPath function in subview controller is not called automatically. It is only called when I move the table view in main UI manually. Any idea?

The sub table view is created as the following code.

```
_tableView = [[UITableView alloc]init];
_mvc = [[meterViewController alloc]initWithMeter:ipAddr protocol:protocol id: meterId];
_tableView.dataSource = _mvc.self;

_tableView.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view addSubview:_tableView];
```

PS: The numberOfSectionsInTableView in subtableview controller is called every 2 seconds, but cellForRowAtIndexPath is only called when start up or I dragged the tableview on main screen to make it redraw.

Answer (score 0):

Following tips may help reload subTableView:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    if(tableView == superTableView){
        [subTableView performSelector:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
        return //superTableView.sectonCount
    }
    else if(tableView == subTableView){
        return //subTableView sectionCount

    }

    return //default Count, you can set 1.
}
```

Comment: _tableView.dataSource = _mvc.self; is it subTableView's dataSource is _mvc?

Comment: Yes, I set up a 2 seconds timer in _mvc and call reloadData in the 2 seconds timer, the numberOfSectionsInTableView and numberOfRowsInSection are called every 2 seconds, but cellForRowAtIndexPath is not, it is only called when start up or I drag the table view to show more cells.

Comment: numberOfRowsInSection return 6, not 0.

Comment: @user3192521 can you NSLog(@"tableView:%@", tableView) to check if all your tableViews get to print, if not, it show your tableView dataSource isn't setup properly

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the delegate isn't setup properly. Make sure you do `self.tableView.delegate = self;`. Self would be your view controller and not your sub view.

You can use your sub view, but you would have to implement the UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource protocols in the sub view custom class, the. Assign the tableview's delegate and data source to the sub view.

Answer (score 0):

It is weird but reloadSection can be used to make the cellForRowAtIndexPath be called.

`NSIndexSet * sections = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:i];
        [self.tableView reloadSections:sections withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];`